# Union two arrays while filling the gaps

Tags: ruby

I have a `day` object. It has two attributes: `name` and `magnitude` where `name` is the name of the day ("Monday", "Tuesday" ....) while `magnitude` is an integer.

I need to build a `week` which must always return an array of 7 `day`s, one for each day of the week.

However, sometimes, the array I get has less than 7 `day`s. I.e.

```
days = [<Day name: "Monday", magnitude: 4>, 
        <Day name: "Friday", magnitude: 3>, 
        <Day name: "Sunday", magnitude: 8>]
```

So, to build the week I came up with the following code

```
default = Date::DAYNAMES.rotate(1).map{ |day| Day.new(name: day, magnitude: 0) }

default.map do |day|
 days.detect do |other|
   other.day == day.day
 end || day
end
```

This works but I find it pretty ugly. I'd rather perform a union between the two arrays. However, I must preserve the order of the `day`s in the array. `Monday` must always be the first day while `Sunday` the last one.

Any ideas on how to improve the code above?

Answer (score 3):

**Data**

```
class Day
  attr_accessor :name, :magnitude
  def initialize(name, magnitude)
    @name = name
    @magnitude = magnitude
  end
end
```

```
days = [["Monday", 4], ["Friday", 3], ["Sunday", 8]].map {|args|
  Day.new(*args) }
  #=> [#<Day:0x00005a1be9157548 @name="Monday", @magnitude=4>,
  #    #<Day:0x00005a1be91574d0 @name="Friday", @magnitude=3>,
  #    #<Day:0x00005a1be91574a8 @name="Sunday", @magnitude=8>]
```

**Code**

```
require 'date'
```

```
h = days.each_with_object({}) { |inst,h| h[inst.name] = inst }
  #=> {"Monday"=>#<Day:0x00005a1be9157548 @name="Monday", @magnitude=4>,
  #    "Friday"=>#<Day:0x00005a1be91574d0 @name="Friday", @magnitude=3>,
  #    "Sunday"=>#<Day:0x00005a1be91574a8 @name="Sunday", @magnitude=8>}
```

```
h.default_proc = ->(h,d) { h[d] = Day.new(d,0) }
  #=> #<Proc:0x00005a1be93ce858@(irb):26 (lambda)>
```

```
h.values_at(*Date::DAYNAMES.rotate(1))
  #=> [#<Day:0x00005a1be9157548 @name="Monday", @magnitude=4>,
  #    #<Day:0x00005a1be93d8ec0 @name="Tuesday", @magnitude=0>,
  #    #<Day:0x00005a1be93d8e98 @name="Wednesday", @magnitude=0>,
  #    #<Day:0x00005a1be93d8e70 @name="Thursday", @magnitude=0>,
  #    #<Day:0x00005a1be91574d0 @name="Friday", @magnitude=3>,
  #    #<Day:0x00005a1be93d8e48 @name="Saturday", @magnitude=0>,
  #    #<Day:0x00005a1be91574a8 @name="Sunday", @magnitude=8>]
```

**Explanation**

See [Hash#default_proc=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) and [Hash#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at). If `h` does not have a key `day` the default proc causes `h` to return a new `Day` object with `@name` equal to the value of `day` and `@magnitude` equal to zero.

The first two expressions could be combined using (for example) [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
h = days.each_with_object({}) { |inst,h| h[inst.name] = inst }.
         tap { |h| h.default_proc = ->(h,d) { h[d] = Day.new(d,0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to map against an array of weekdays:

```
weekdays = %w(Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday)
```

Where you can use the constant `Date::DAYNAMES` available requiring the `date` library.

Then, given your array (I'm not using the class `Day`) for example as

```
days = [ ['Monday', 4], ['Friday', 3], ['Sunday', 8] ]
```

you can do:

```
weekdays.map { |weekday| days.find { |e| e.first == weekday } || [weekday, 0] }
#=> [["Monday", 4], ["Tuesday", 0], ["Wednesday", 0], ["Thursday", 0], ["Friday", 3], ["Saturday", 0], ["Sunday", 8]]
```

Or, using your class:

```
weekdays.map { |weekday| days.find { |e| e.name == weekday } || Day.new(weekday, 0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a similar answer as already given by [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59133930/3982562). However I'd use the following:

```
day_lookup = days.to_h { |day| [day.name, day] }
day_lookup.default_proc = ->(_, name) { Day.new(name: name, magnitude: 0) }
days = day_lookup.values_at(*Date::DAYNAMES.rotate(1))
```

So, what did I change? If you use Ruby 2.6.0 or greater you can use [`Array#to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-to_h) with a block, which makes creating a hash from array a lot cleaner in my opinion.

Secondly I only return a default value if a name is not present, but don't set the value in the `day_lookup` hash. If you need to access a day multiple times this might be a good idea to do, however in this scenario we only call [`values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) once and then we're done with the hash.